# Why does my Droid RAZR play the new email notification when I visit my inbox on my PC?

Tags: email, notifications, gmail, motorola-droid-razr

This is truly a mystery to me.  When I get new email, it's normal for me to receive an audio notification on my Droid RAZR.  However, when I visit my Gmail Inbox via my browser on my PC, my Droid RAZR plays the notification sound.  I'm not even really sure how it knows what I'm doing.  I realize it's connected to Gmail, but it's still quite strange.

This morning I sat down at my computer to find I had several new emails.  I began reading and managing them in Gmail (on my PC), and during this time my phone notified me of new email at least 3 times, yet I didn't actually receive any 'new' email at that time.  It was all because I was going to my Gmail Inbox.

How does my phone know that I've done this?  Sometimes I don't even really have to DO anything.  If I already have a browser tab with my Inbox, and then at some point I simply go to that tab and there happens to be new email in it, within a few seconds my phone will notify me.  It's quite bizarre.

What is the explanation for this?

**Recent example:**
I was just browsing the internet on my PC when I noticed I had some incoming emails (my phone played the audio notification, and I also can tell via my gmail notifier app in my system tray). I was watching YouTube videos at the time.  After a few minutes I left YouTube and went to gmail.com, to my Inbox.  I clicked to view the first unread email there.  During this process, my phone played the incoming email audio notification not just once, but twice.  This is before actually doing anything with any email.  All I did was view it.  I really don't understand why/how this happens.

**Update to recent example:**
After updating this post with the recent example I just gave, I went back to my Inbox tab (yes, I had left my Gmail Inbox open in another Firefox tab).  When I went to the tab, which still contained a couple unread messages as I had not viewed them all yet, my phone played the notification AGAIN.  I really want to know why this happens.

Comment: Might you have moved a mail into your inbox? The client does not really now whether a mail is "new" -- just that it's "new to the client" in terms it was not there when it checked last (at least that's how it works with IMAP).

Comment: I'm not moving anything.  All I'm doing is looking at the Inbox on my PC, and when I do that, my phone notifies me.  Granted, it isn't every single time I visit the Inbox.  It's only if there have been new items since last time I visited.  Still, how would the phone know?

Comment: @Izzy, I just updated my post with a recent example of this.

Comment: That really looks weird. Only understandable reason would be if there were multiple new mails: 1) phone sounds for 1st new mail 2) second new mail arrives, while you 3) open your inbox on the computer. Accidentally, just while you're doing so, 4) your phone notices the 2nd new mail. So "new mail sound *while visiting your inbox* is nothing but a coincidence.

Comment: I'm not actually receiving any mail while (or anywhere near the time) that I visit my Inbox on the PC... and it happens every time, so there's no way I accept that it's a coincidence.

Comment: Another example from just now.  Over an hour ago I received several emails from my boss.  My phone, of course, notified me.  I was playing a game so I didn't open them right away. During the game I paused to email a friend.  This required me to go to Gmail, where I saw my Inbox (I don't remember if the phone did anything then).  I then went back to playing, leaving the Inbox open.  After I was done, I returned to the Inbox and began reading the mail.  For each unread email I viewed, my phone played another notification.  No new emails were coming in.

Comment: Must be some really weird thing, I've never heard such. I'm not using GMail that frequent, maybe it has some strange setting for this? I do not expect such (*notify me whenever some mail changes its status from "unread" to "read" and it was not done by this client*), but that at least would be a rational explanation...

Comment: This behavior used to happen to me as well on the Stock Rom. It seemed as if the Gmail App regarded any change as a new mail event. So if I read/deleted a mail on the web or my iPad, the new mail notification would occur.

Comment: @mcchots, well, it's nice to know I'm not the only one, but it's still a strange and unsolved mystery.

Comment: @vertigoelectric I don't know if it is in ICS or Motorola's code, but I don't have the problem in CM10.1. It was something that annoyed me greatly with the Stock ROM.

Comment: This is really aggravating me.  I hope someone can help me figure out a way to stop it.